# Android app label color

Tags: android, colors, themes, label

I don't want to create any custom layout for app label, just want to change it's color to white (now it's black). How could I do that?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>

</style>

<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/bg_blue_solid_onclick</item> 
//////CHANGE label color    
</style>
</resources>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50181812/5045878 this answer shows the easiest way of doing so.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

styles.xml

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
         <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>

</style>
<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
         <item name="android:background">#FF9D21</item>
         <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/MyActionBarTitleText</item>
</style> 
<style name="MyActionBarTitleText"
           parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/red</item>
</style>
```

colors.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="red">#FF0000</color>
</resources>
```

For more info

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html#CustomText

Snap

[image]

Edit : For making it bold

```
 <style name="MyActionBarTitleText"
           parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/red</item>
        <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
 </style>
```

Comment: thanks, it works! maybe I can also make the text bold in there or I need aditional layout?

Comment: @user3082220 you need have any additional fpr baking text bold. You can use a spannable string and set it to textview for this you need a custom view for action bar i guess. i guess you do that using styles also

Comment: @user3082220 use this `<item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>` and check the edit fro that

Answer (score 1):

None of the previous answers worked for me, so I'm showing the one that worked in my case.

```
<style name="AppThemeCustom" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@android:color/black</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/white</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/MyTitleTextStyle</item>
    <!-- Support library compatibility -->
    <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/MyTitleTextStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="MyTitleTextStyle" 
  parent="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/black</item>
</style>
```

I wish if you find yourself in my situation this solution save your day. LOL

Answer (score 0):

You need to style the `android:titleTextStyle` in your ActionBar.

```
<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar">
     <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/MyTextTitle</item>
</style>

<style name="MyTextTitle" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

**You can see this in Android Documentation: [Customize the Text Color in ActionBar](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html#CustomText)**

Hope this helps.

Comment: i think it should be `parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title"`

Answer (score 0):

in styles.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />
```

in toolbar

```
android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
```