# Customizing title bar in Android. Getting Exception You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme

Tags: android, titlebar

Search a lot but nothing found useful.

I am creating a simple app with my customized Title bar but not getting so far from days. I am  using this https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html.

**Manifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.title"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:theme="@style/CustomActionBarTheme"//title bar
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.title.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I have created theme.xml like *res/values/themes.xml*.

**Code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <!-- the theme applied to the application or activity -->
    <style name="CustomActionBarTheme"
           parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>

        <!-- Support library compatibility -->
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    </style>

    <!-- ActionBar styles -->
    <style name="MyActionBar"
           parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
        <item name="android:background">#CCCCCC</item>

        <!-- Support library compatibility -->
    </style>
</resources>
```

Getting Exception :( 
**logcat:**

```
04-22 11:37:21.755: E/test(11652): Exception
04-22 11:37:21.757: E/AndroidRuntime(11652): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-22 11:37:21.757: E/AndroidRuntime(11652): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.title/com.example.title.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
04-22 11:37:21.757: E/AndroidRuntime(11652):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2306)
04-22 11:37:21.757: E/AndroidRuntime(11652):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2358)
04-22 11:37:21.757: E/AndroidRuntime(11652):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:156)
04-22 11:37:21.757: E/AndroidRuntime(11652):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1340)
04-22 11:37:21.757: E/AndroidRuntime(11652):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-22 11:37:21.757: E/AndroidRuntime(11652):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
04-22 11:37:21.757: E/AndroidRuntime(11652):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299)
04-22 11:37:21.757: E/AndroidRuntime(11652):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-22 11:37:21.757: E/AndroidRuntime(11652):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-22 11:37:21.757: E/AndroidRuntime(11652):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
04-22 11:37:21.757: E/AndroidRuntime(11652):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
04-22 11:37:21.757: E/AndroidRuntime(11652):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-22 11:37:21.757: E/AndroidRuntime(11652): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
04-22 11:37:21.757: E/AndroidRuntime(11652):    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegate.onCreate(ActionBarActivityDelegate.java:111)
04-22 11:37:21.757: E/AndroidRuntime(11652):    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.onCreate(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:58)
04-22 11:37:21.757: E/AndroidRuntime(11652):    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onCreate(ActionBarActivity.java:98)
04-22 11:37:21.757: E/AndroidRuntime(11652):    at com.example.title.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:18)
04-22 11:37:21.757: E/AndroidRuntime(11652):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5182)
04-22 11:37:21.757: E/AndroidRuntime(11652):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1081)
04-22 11:37:21.757: E/AndroidRuntime(11652):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2270)
04-22 11:37:21.757: E/AndroidRuntime(11652):    ... 11 more
```

Guide me with this please

Comment: check this carefully `parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse"` there is no theme found for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your MainActivity probably extends from ActionBarActivity. And you are probably referencing AppCompat. So you need to use `Theme.AppCompat`.

Also you have  `android:minSdkVersion="11"`. So there is no need to extend `ActionBarActivty` and no need to reference `AppCompat` and no need for `Theme.AppCompat`

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html

Also check

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html

Comment: yes my MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity. Should i remove this????? Explain me i don't understand properly

Comment: @Manwal yes you need to extend Activity and there is no need for you to reference AppCompat. Check the docs there is enough info there. ActionBar is available in api level 11. No need to use support library for backward compatibility

Comment: @Manwal check this . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20597224/andoid-app-label-color/20597535#20597535. First of all there is no need for AppCompat. You have `@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"`

Comment: Ya work like a charm. When i use http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20597224/andoid-app-label-color/20597535#20597535 App background is not white not why?? i want white.

Comment: Sorry for this but please give me code how can i change background white? and what should i do if i want text and center of title bar?

Comment: @Manwal ask a different question. You will need a custom layout and then set the same to action bar. I can't mention it here. Do ask a new question

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51167/discussion-between-raghunandan-and-manwal)