# Android how to change overview label color?

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

I have my style.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

and my color.xml:

```
<color name="colorPrimary">#FC7E0D</color>
<color name="colorPrimaryDark">#E07514</color>
<color name="colorAccent">#EF4B07</color>
```

It's my overview
[image]

I want to make my label white color, but how? I know about TaskDescription, but in this case taskdescription does not help me.

My manifest.xml:

```
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

MainActivity.class:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    private Toolbar toolbar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        navigationView.getMenu().performIdentifierAction(R.id.nav_main, 0);
    }

    ...other code...
```

MainActivity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/container_body"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: are you using actionbar without `ToolBar`  or with `ToolBar`?

Comment: which label do you want as a black ? the one which is with "Hello World!" text or the Title of actionbar ?

Comment: #FC7E0D  <color name="colorPrimary">#FC7E0D</color> change this color

Comment: @user1140237 Only toolbar and AppCompatActivity

Comment: @user1140237 title of actionbar

Comment: @Madhur this change background, not label color

Comment: Change `textColorPrimary` (according to the official documentation: http://developer.android.com/training/material/theme.html) or use the light theme which has it white by default.

Comment: check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20597224/android-app-label-color

Answer (score 0):

If you are using tooldbar than you can change color from your activity. and style also but i would suggest you to change it from activity.

In below Code ToolBar id is `ab_tool` you can give it whatever in your xml 
Keep below code in your Activity.

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.ab_tool);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);        
toolbar.setTitleTextColor(Color.WHITE);
```

If ActionBar is without Toolbar than need to change ActionBar TextView Text color

```
 int titleTextViewResourceID = getResources().getIdentifier("action_bar_title", "id", "android");
        TextView txtActionBarTitle = (TextView) findViewById(titleTextViewResourceID);
        txtActionBarTitle.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
```

**Update**

AFAIK that is default behavior which is displaying on most recent app.

Title Color is taking by default from internally based on `colorPrimary` given in style for actionbar or toolbar

System will give title color internally  based on `colorPrimary`.

***System will put ActionBar with close button & application icon in most recent apps thumbnail even in your app you are not using ActionBar , toolbar style anything.***

***Case 1***
Here if you give dark color Reddish color(Red scale is more) which you gave in question than it will take **Black** color as a title color in most recent app even if you give White Color to the title text from xml or runtime in activity.

[Sample Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/09OsQ.gif)

```
<color name="colorPrimary">#FC7E0D</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#E07514</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">#EF4B07</color>

<style name="AppThemeSliderToolbar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/slider_bg_primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/slider_bg_primary_dark</item>
</style>
```

***Case 2***
If you give light color to `colorPrimary` than system will take black color internally.

```
<style name="AppThemeSliderToolbar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/my_primary_light</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/slider_bg_primary_dark</item>
</style>

<color name="slider_bg_primary_dark">#FF5722</color>
<color name="my_primary_light">#B3E5FC</color>
```

[Sample Image case2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lrSwl.gif)

***How can you change that to White Color***
Use below color combination to get white color on most recent app actionbar.

```
<color name="slider_bg_primary">#ff5b45</color>
<color name="slider_bg_primary_dark">#FF5722</color>

 <style name="AppThemeSliderToolbar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/slider_bg_primary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/slider_bg_primary_dark</item>
 </style>
```

Used `AppThemeSliderToolbar` theme in manifest for activity for above all case

[White Color TItle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KBey3.gif)

Comment: @StarSquad where you have apply toolbar title color .. ? `toolbar.setTitleTextColor(Color.WHITE);`

Comment: @user114027 I apply, but this didnt work and i remove this code.

Comment: @StarSquad I think you are asking like why its not displaying White color in recent app ?