# how to change android label text color in xamarin?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, xamarin.android, android-theme

I am using xamarin to develop an app but cant figure out how to change the text color of the app title in the `Style.xml` that i am using is given below.

[**Expected output**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qnExi.jpg)

```
<resources>
    <style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Material.Light">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:colorPrimary">#00d1ff</item>
    <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">#40c5e9</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#40c5e9</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#FFFFFF</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

Comment: there is not difference in how you define style in Xamarin or native. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20597224/android-app-label-color

Comment: tried it already,did not work for me

Comment: `android:titleTextStyle` too?

Comment: Remove `<item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>` and then try. @VedSarkar

Comment: that too didnt work

Comment: Can you clarify something for me. I see on your expected out JPG that you clicked the Overview button on the device, so is this when you want your ActionBar text color to be white? or when the app is in full view do you want to display the ActionBar with white text? or Both?

Comment: When my app is in full view the text is white...but when I press overview the label color changes to black.I want both of them to be white !

Comment: This one worked for me, Here is one solution. Looks like other people are having trouble changing text color while on overview.  Put this inside your OnCreate method of your layout activity.  `Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.DecodeResource(Resources, Resource.Drawable.Icon);

   TaskDescription taskDesc = new TaskDescription("Listy", bm, Color.Rgb(24, 80, 130));
   SetTaskDescription(taskDesc);`

Comment: Thanks man this works, but when I change the color to Rgb(0, 209, 255) the label goes back to black !!

Comment: the black label inconvenience is caused due to colorPrimary. If it is too light then the text color changes to black.

Answer (score 0):

put you colors in colors.xml and reference them like

```
<item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/green</item>
```