# How can I painlessly change my app Title text color?

Tags: android, title

[Android Studio UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/96uEx.jpg)[Application UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sMnCU.jpg)

See attached Android Studio UI image: I want to change the Title Text COLOR from white to gray; every XML variation I have tried has not worked; where in the attached activity_scrolling.xml file can I change the Title text to gray - and it work?

How do I painlessly change the text color from white to gray for my application Title?  I am using Android Studio 2.3.3 and have poured through the XML files for style, color, and my activity XML files making attempts at changing the Title text color from white to gray and have not been successful doing such a simple task - it is not intuitive how to do this.  Please help, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

This should work. Go to your `styles.xml`s file.

```
<style name="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title" parent="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat">

    <item name="android:textSize">TEXT_SIZE_HERE</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">COLOR_RESOURCE_HERE</item>
    <item name="android:fontFamily">FONT_HERE</item>
</style>
```

Edit accordingly.
Video tutorial here [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=510WE8CmiXI][1]

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution for you.

Go to styles.xml in res->values and in your theme add one item like this:

```
<item name="titleTextColor">@color/yourColorTitle</item>
```

Now you just have to add the desired color in the colors.xml resource file in res->values->colors.xml like this:

```
<color name="yourColorTitle">#000000</color>
```

Answer (score 2):

Go into styles.xml and inside style AppTheme add

`<item name="android:textColorPrimary">#b5b5b5</item>`

where #b5b5b5 is grey color. You can insert any color you want.

Complete code looks like this (if someone can't find AppTheme):

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#b5b5b5</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your XML file, for the **TextView**   element, add the `android:textColor` attribute, with the choice of your color as its value.

```
<TextView
 android:id..
 android:layout_width..
 android:layout_height..
 android:text=..
 android:textColor="#D3D3D3"
/>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think the question was answered: How do I painlessly change the text COLOR from white to gray for my APPLICATION TITLE - the app title is not in a textview attribute?

Answer (score 0):

For this, you need to find the `AnroidManifest.xml` file.

Using your IDE navigate to `app -> src -> main ->  AnroidManifest.xml`

**Option 1:** If you're in android studio go inside `AndroidManifest.xml` and double click on `android:label="@string/app_name"` and it will take you to where you can change the value to whatever you want

**Option2:** Directly go to `app -> src -> main ->  res -> values -> strings.xml` and change the name to whatever you want.

***NOTE:*** Please note that it is not recommended to hard code the value of the app name like `android:label="HARDCODED name"` as this will break the app in case you want to include features like a translation.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think the question was answered: How do I painlessly change the text COLOR from white to gray for my application Title?

Answer (score -1):

I noticed that the choice made in themes.xml file influences the color of the app title, for example if you use DayNight.DarkActionBar like this

[image]

You will have white color for your title, then if you use Light like this [image]

your title will be black